# How should I ask reasonably similar questions with minor variations (or should I be going for a more general canonical question?)

Tags: discussion

I'm currently clearing out my cable drawer and finding all sorts of oddball things - I'm currently doing some simple functional tests on ethernet and USB cables and weeding out the infirm and weak.

Now, some of these cables are unusual enough that I find them baffling like [2 paired ethernet cables](https://superuser.com/questions/701273/what-would-be-the-disadvantages-of-using-a-4-stranded-ethernet-cable), and now, flat ethernet cables. These are *physically* different enough from my regular cat 5 cables that I'm curious about them, and have engaged in functional testing (the flat stuff seems marginally *better*, while 4 stranded cable is garbage).

I suppose the perfect solution would be to test these cables myself and write a blog post. However, I'm wondering - what would be the best way to handle very similar questions on the same functions but with potentially widely varying answers?

If I *had* wanted to ask a question on flat cables, or intend to, how best do I do it? Do I ask a general question, include the information from the other question, and potentially ask it to be merged? Ask a seperate question for flat cables?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly—what would the actual question be?

Comment: Either "What would be the disadvantages of a flat cable?" or a cable equivilent of [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/366221/differences-between-cherry-mechanical-keyboard-switches) - practically "what should I be looking at when selecting an ethernet cable?"

Comment: We had some paired ethernet cables with 4 connections at each end and a material sheeth holding the cables together. It had come with some conferencing equipment. The only time I have seen a flat cable similar to the one you are talking about is with a Cisco Console cable, which has an RS-232 connector on one end and an ethernet on the other. The fact is was flat seemed irrelevant. I work for an Engineering company and the engineers tell me that Cat6 is significantly better quality than Cat5e (according to the specs and standards) however in reality I have never noticed.